# Passing Multidimensional arrays to functions as Pointers

Tags: c, arrays, function, pointers, multidimensional-array

I have to pass two arrays ( A and B with dimensions of 5X4) to two functions called FUNCTION_1 and FUNCTION_2. Both of arrays columns and rows should be passed as POINTERS. FUNCTION_1 will take each element of A array and calculate the sum of prime factors of  each element located in A( (with the help of another function called sumPrime), then it will store these sums in array B. FUNCTION_2 has to print both of A and B arrays. ( The normal numbers array, and the prime factors sums array). There are some additions in the program which are not important now but I am going to show them too in respect of clearness.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define ROW 5
#define COL 4
# include <math.h>
int sumPrime(int number){
     int factor = 2;
     int sum=0;

    while(1!=number){
       if(number%factor==0){
          number /= factor;
          sum+=factor;

          factor = 2;
          continue;
        }
        factor++;
    }

    return sum;
}
int FUNCTION_1(int *a[][20],int *b[][20],int row, int col){
    int c,d;
    for(c=0;c<row;c++){
        for(d=0;d<col;d++){
             b[c][d]=sumPrime(a[c][d]);
            return b[c][d];
        }
    }


}
void FUNCTION_2(int *x[][20],int *y[][20],int rows, int cols){
    printf(" \n A matrix is :\n");
    int e,f;
    for(e=0;e<rows;e++){
        for(f=0;f<cols;f++){
            printf("A[%d][%d] is %d\n",e,f,x[e][f]);



        }
    }
    printf("\n B matrix is:\n");
    for(e=0;e<rows;e++){
        for(f=0;f<cols;f++){
            printf("A[%d][%d] is %d\n",e,f,FUNCTION_1(x,rows,cols,y,rows,cols));



        }
    } 
}






int main(){


    int A[ROW][COL]={0};
    int B[ROW][COL]={0};
    int x=1;
    int i;
    int j;

    for(i=0;i<ROW;i++){

        for(j=0;j<COL;j++){
            A[i][j]=x;
            x=x+2;

        }                                   
    }
    printf("%d",A[0][0]);




    return 0;

}
```

When trying to perform FUNCTION_1 or FUNCTION_2 I get many errors or even when defining the functions. There is no problem with defining A matrix or prime function! HELP!!

Comment: In addition, should I apply FUNCTION_1 in the main function or applying FUNCTION_2 is enough as well? What would be the corresponding code in the main function?

Comment: Sorry for that I think I meant pointers.

Comment: Regardless, try searching this site rather than just posting to it: [`[c] multi-dimension array parameters`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bc%5D+multi-dimension+array+parameters) would be a good place to start.

Comment: You probably need to replace argument declarations like `int *a[][20]` to `int a[][20]` or `int (*a)[20]`.

Comment: I assume my problem is dealing with multi arrays, pointers, and calling their functions. Just need a little push for that.

Answer (score 1):

Your definition for a matrix is wrong ..
Use :
`func(int* a[20] , int cols)`
in this case you will have 20 rows , 
or 
`func(int a[][20] , int rows)`
And define some macro for the columns if it is fixed value .

Comment: But each function contains two matrices not just 1 how am I going to define for this case? And how should I call these functions in the main?

Comment: if the matrix size is know at compalation time ( as you defined ROW and COL ) , then the best method is - func( int a[ROW][COL],int b[ROW][COL] )

Comment: And when using from main : int a[ROW][COL] = values ... and send only the param name " func(a,b) " .

Comment: In that case I am able to print A matrix but B still zero, and where is the turn of pointers to arrays here? I don't see any *. Any idea?